# Solve using either master theorem or by expansion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, substitution, recurrence, master-theorem

I have two questions, which I have trying but unable to figure them out.
1) () = ( − 1) + ^4
2) () = 2 (/2) +  lg

For first one, I am assuming substitution (am I correct?), and got kb + T(n-k). Pretty sure that's wrong so need help with it.

For the second one, I have no idea at all...

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) So you got

[image]

...? I don't know how you obtained this but it's certainly incorrect.

This is basically the summation of the 4th power of all integers up to `n`. The standard formula for this is:

[image]

---

2) We can find a pattern if we keep expanding this:

[image]

The limit `log n - 1` is because we keep dividing the parameter to `T` by 2, so the substitution as above can continue for `log n` lines until, say `T(1)` or wherever the stopping condition is. Continuing using the *logarithm rules* (google them if you don't know):

[image]

Both summations have `log n` terms. Since the 1st summation does not depend on `i` at all, we simply multiply by `log n`. The 2nd summation is given by a standard formula for summation of integers from 1 (or 0, doesn't matter in this case):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just a doubt, how did you get from the 3rd '=' to the 4th? Do not really understand the subsequent steps...

Comment: @dancerdiver101 I've included a more thorough explanation of the steps. Hope that helps.